# Merging 2 MySQL Databases

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 Databases that basically have the same structure, but different data. (The older Database has 2 extra tables) Is there any way for me to combine the 2 Databases into one, with the extra tables).

Is there any easy way to do this? Importing a dump of the old Database into the new one throws errors.

Notes:
I can SSH into the server to combine the databases, I can also use PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Hi there, what kind of errors are thrown?

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table 'magento.#sql-2c5_24e' (errno: 121) is the error I get when I try to add the dump to the database (both in SSH and PHPMyAdmin)

Comment: "throws errors" is meaningless when you're trying to get help for a problem. Post the *exact* error message you're getting if you want to get an answer. Posting "throws errors" is a waste of both your time and that of the people reading your question.

Comment: I realized that after Nick asked. Read my above comment. It's 2 Magento Databases if that helps at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1005/121 is usually a foreign key violation. If the table you're loading is a target of (or has) any foreign keys, most likely the corresponding parent (or child) records aren't available, killing the load.

Comment: I disabled Foreign Key Checks when I created the dump, but I guess that isn't a fix all. Thanks!

Comment: You need to disable it at load time as well.